# Selenium Python problema con pseudo elemento

Tags: python, selenium, scraping, pseudoelementos

Estoy realizando un proyecto en selenium, la idea es acceder a una web y descargar un archivo. Digamos que está pensando en 3 partes.

1ra parte está lista, el código permite entrar a la página, clickear.

2da parte está lista, el código permite enviar números a un formulario y clickear en buscar.

y 3ra parte, he aquí el problema, el código **debería** clickear (en la lupa), entrar a una página y clickear en descarga. Sin embargo, no logro hacer click en el lugar deseado (la lupa) pues como indica el título, existe un pseudo element. Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código que dejo a continuación no funciona el click (en variable detalle_causa)

```py
if t_rol == rol_yr:
        rol_c0.append(t_rol)
        materias_e_c0.append(t_tiporecurso)
        carat_c0.append(t_caratulado)
        fecha_c0.append(t_fecha)
        estado_c0.append(t_estado)
        data = {"ROL": rol_c0,"TIPO RECURSO":materias_e_c0, "CARATULADO":carat_c0, "FECHA":fecha_c0, "ESTADO":estado_c0}
        sleep(3)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df)
        sleep(3)
        detalle_causa = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'i.fa.fa-search.fa-lg').click()
        df.to_csv('2022_cs_p2.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
        sleep(2)

 else:
     print("No era")
```

Agradezco desde ya sus respuestas y comentarios.

Comment: Evita agregar imágenes solo en el caso de ser necesario, no todos pueden verlas, adjunta el código que hayas realizado, con esto te ayudas a recibir una mejor respuesta. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: Finalmente la solución era darle más tiempo al buscador para hacer click. Se resuelve agregando: sleep(3), antes y después de detalle_causa.